# Java: How to read multiple scanner values for one int

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

I have been trying to figure out how calculate the area and volume based on the input obtain from the `Scanner` Class. The exercise consist of receiving multiple pair of radius and height at once.

I have written the methods and tested them, so those should be working. The problem I am having is when I want to use inputs from 'Scanner' and use them to make the calculations.

Here is my code (I did not include the methods):

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

    int radius = 0;
    int height = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter values ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] items = input.split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[items.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)  
        {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
        } 

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length/2; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = radius;
        numbers[i + 1] = height;

        double result = area(radius);
        double result1 = area (radius,height);
        double result2 = volume (radius,height);

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("r = " + radius + "    ");
        System.out.print("h = " + height);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Base area:    ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", result);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Surface area: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", result1);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Volym:            ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", result2);
        System.out.println("");
    }
    keyboard.nextLine();
```

Those are the Results:

```
Input: 2 4 5 1

Output: 


r = 0    h = 0

Base area:        0.00

Surface area:     0.00

Volym:            0.00



r = 0    h = 0

Base area:        0.00

Surface area:     0.00

Volym:            0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i+=2)
{
    radius = numbers[i];
    height = numbers[i + 1];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to him more about it? why his `numbers.length/2` is wrong .

Comment: because He wants to calculate the area of all the radius and height after searching the entire array rather than half of them. Notice the i+=2 in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are wrong:

```
numbers[i] = radius;
numbers[i + 1] = height;
```

`radius` and `height` should be on the left hand side:

```
radius = numbers[i];
height = numbers[i + 1];
```

Also, if you want to "group" the inputs into pairs, this won't work:

```
radius = numbers[i];
height = numbers[i + 1];
```

This will just group the input like "(0, 1), (1, 2)". Use this instead;

```
radius = numbers[i * 2];
height = numbers[i * 2 + 1];
```

Comment: That worked really good for the first run but on the second it started on numbers[1], and not numbers[2]. So now it has to increment twice for each run. I tried:
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length/2; i += 2)
but that didn't work.

Comment: @xarroo Did you use `numbers[i * 2]` and `numbers[i * 2 + 1]` as I said in the last part?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int radius = 0;
    int height = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter values ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] items = input.split(" ");
    int[] numbers;

    if(items.length % 2 == 0){ //Making sure you are having even number of inputs
        numbers = new int[items.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0,j = -1; i < numbers.length / 2; i++){
            radius = numbers[++j];
            height = numbers[++j];
            System.out.println("radius: " + radius + " height: " + height);

            //Write Your Area Volume Code Here and use the radius and height which is there in the loop for calculation
            //Your code goes here
            //Your code ends here
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Incorrect input provided");
    }
    keyboard.close();
}}
```

Give this piece a try. The sample output is provided below:

Enter values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
radius: 1 height: 2
radius: 3 height: 4
radius: 5 height: 6
radius: 7 height: 8
radius: 9 height: 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention: radius and height don’t get new values after its first initialization

Answer (score 0):

try some as:

```
public class NewMain
{
class Crate
{
    public int radius;
    public int height;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter values ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] items = input.split(" ");
    Crate[] numbers = new Crate[items.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++)
    {
        numbers[i].radius = Integer.parseInt(items[i * 2]);
        numbers[i].height = Integer.parseInt(items[i * 2 + 1]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this solution.

The method `processItems()` cleans all the `white-spaces` between numbers and this line of code `if (integers.length % 2 == 0)` makes sure we have even number of inputs. So we have always a **pair of numbers** (*Radius* and *Height*).

I also created a class `InputPair` and an array of `InputPair` to print the pairs an maintain modularity.

You can test with this for even number of inputs:

> 2  9 4 7 5 6 7  1 3 8 12  5 8 2 3 9 2  9 2   7

And this for odd  number of inputs:

> 2  9 4  5 6 7  1 3 8 12  5 8 6 3 9 2  9 2   7

You can find here the [**full Java code**](https://gist.github.com/teocci/15266e293d83feb48eb8333654a72fa7)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static class InputPair {
        public int radius;
        public int height;

        public InputPair() {}

        public void printValues() {
            System.out.println("Radius: " + radius + " Height: " + height);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter values ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        String[] items = input.split(" ");
        Integer[] integers = processItems(items);
        InputPair[] values = new InputPair[integers.length];

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
        System.out.println("items length:  " + items.length);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
        System.out.println("items length:  " + integers.length);

        if (integers.length % 2 == 0) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.length / 2; i++) {
                System.out.print("Index:  " + i + " ");
                try {
                    values[i] = new InputPair();
                    values[i].radius = integers[i * 2];
                    values[i].height = integers[i * 2 + 1];
                    values[i].printValues();
                } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                    System.out.println("Error NullPointerException");
                }

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number of values bust be an even number. ");
        }
    }

    private static Integer[] processItems(String[] items) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : items) {
            //Do your stuff here
            s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            if (!s.equals("")) {
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }
        }

        Integer[] stockArr = new Integer[numbers.size()];
        return numbers.toArray(stockArr);
    }
}
```